# Is there a limit of factors in `dplyr::group_by`?

Tags: r, dplyr, lag

I'm struggling on how can I calculate the wear of a component using the `lag` of a variable. However, I need to calculate the wear on different groups, so I'm using the `group_by` function, but here's a problem, when I use the variable that I need to group, this results in a column of "NA's", but when I test by grouping one another variable that has fewer factors the calculation works.

The dataframe I'm using has `4093902` rows and `52` lines. The variable I need to group to perform my wear calculation has `90183` factors. The other one that I tested and it worked had `11321` factors.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
final_date = result_data %>%
arrange((time)) %>%
  group_by(id_specific)%>%
  mutate(wear = dplyr::lag(some_value, n = 1, default = NA) - some_value)
```

Does anyone know if there is a factor limit for grouping? Or any other tips on how I can perform this calculation?

Comment: when I use the column `id_specific`, there is no result, only NA's were created

Comment: right, but the group have a lot of more rows

Comment: I tried, and it returns only `NA's` for `wear`.

Comment: I tried with another column in `group_by` and it works... I can't understand

Comment: if the problem is the NA in the subtraction, any hint on how can I avoid them?

Comment: i.e. you may do ` mutate(wear = rowSums(cbind(dplyr::lag(some_value, n = 1, default = NA),  -1 * some_value), na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: Works for me! Thank you very much!

Comment: If you want to make an answer I mark as right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NA` can be a result of either `lag` which returns the first value by default as `NA` or from the other column value which can also be `NA`.  Thus, when we do the `-` (or any arithmetic) if there is any NA in the lhs or rhs, it returns `NA`.  One option is to make use of a function (`rowSums`) that can use `na.rm = TRUE`

```
library(dplyr)
final_date <- result_data %>%
arrange((time)) %>%
  group_by(id_specific)%>%
  mutate(some_value_new = dplyr::lag(some_value, n = 1,
             default = NA)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(wear = rowSums(cbind(some_value_new, -1 * some_value), 
              na.rm = TRUE), some_value_new = NULL)
```

NOTE: It is also better to `ungroup` before doing the `rowSums` to get some efficiency

Comment: the first element of each group is negative, do you know how can I set them as zero?

Comment: They are like this: ` 2020-11-02    26.1    -26.1 `. 
I.e., the same value, but negative

Comment: @DR15 not clear.  Is this a single string or three columns?.  If you want to set them as zero.  `mutate(new_column = replace(some_value, 1, 0))` after grouping

Comment: <date>               <dbl>    <dbl>

Comment: 1 2020-11-26            25.5  -25.5

Comment: @DR15 ok, If you check my updated comment, you can `replace` the 1st element with 0

Comment: I should set `group_by(id_specific)%>% mutate(new_column = replace(some_value, 1, 0)) ...` ?

Comment: yes, the `1` is the position index i.e the first element per group.  I changed the column name in case you want to keep the original column as it is